# 5-Month-Old Puppy Barks/Growls When Other People Play With Him

Tags: dogs, behavior

I have a 5-month-old Shepherd/Lab mix who's generally very sweet -- but I've noticed that if people play with them a bit he gets a bit tense and barks at them until I tell him to stop. Not necessarily rough play but just things like dancing around him or play putting their forehead against his a few times or circling his head, etc.

Since he's only five months old, I was hoping I could train him out of this. I've been attempting to expose him to as much as possible as a puppy so he doesn't get freaked out about things, so I suppose it's partially just that he hasn't been around a *ton* of people and especially ones that play with him as opposed to just petting.

Is there a way to expose him more to this behavior without making him more aggressive? (Also is part of this him thinking that people he doesn't know that play like this he should play with like he plays with dogs?)

Comment: Has he been  desexed?

Comment: @YvetteColomb  Not yet! Vet wants me to wait until he's six months. So I should have an appt in about a month.

Comment: That's ok, it was a question, as desexing makes a difference to behaviour.

Comment: how's the rest of his body language? Is he fairly relaxed or stiff?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek He doesn't seem like he's ready to pounce or anything -- but he's definitely looked like he would potentially bite them, though it also looks like he could be biting them in play-mode like he would with other dogs/puppies.